# TYPO3 6.2 get Properties with values of Table

Tags: properties, mapping, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have the following problem: When I use a Model/Repository with a different mapping, I don't get any property and values.

I've mapped the Repository to fetch the data from table `sys_files`.
I do get the `UID`, I also do get the `PID`. Unfortunately, I do not get any other property or the value.

My Repository is a simple Repository mapped to `sys_files`.

Unfortunately, I do not get any orther property.

Thanks a lot.

Greetz

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the mapping in the `ext_typoscript_setup.txt`?

```
config.tx_extbase {
  persistence {
    classes {
      Vendor\Package\Domain\Model\MyModel {
        mapping {
          tableName = sys_file
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You also need to assign the needed fields in your domain model.

```
namespace Vendor\Package\Domain\Model;

class MyModel
{
  /**
   * @var string
   */
  protected $identifier;

  public function getIdentifier()
  {
    return $this->identifier;
  }

  public function setIdentifier($identifier)
  {
    $this->identifier = $identifier;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello René,yes. I have a propper mapping. I do get > 3000 models. The only property which is'n null or 0 is UID.
All uid's are in the database :)

Comment: Did you have the properties definied in your domain model? With getter and setter?

Comment: well, no. i thought that i don't have to do that. i will try it asap, thanks!

Comment: Data from the table is only accessable if they are declared in the domain model. There are no magic getter/setter.

Answer (score 0):

There is a checklist when you mapping a `model` to a `table`:

**1.** Create the ext_typoscript_setup.txt file in the extension root path.

There you have to write the following code:

```
config.tx_extbase{
    persistence {
        classes {
            YourModel.mapping{
                table = table_you_want_to_map
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

Avoid to add `backslash` before `model` `namespace`

**3.** Clear cache from install tool. If nothing happens, then, try to delete the typo3temp/autoload folder.

**4.** The fields from the model should be camelCase.

Example of `field`: `field_name` in your model will be `fieldName`

**5.** Check the getters in your model.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I did edit the existing setup.txt as instructed.
In my table I have the column "identifier_hash" which I try to access by using protected $identifierHash, getIdentifierHash() and setIdentifierHash($hash).
Unfortunately, the value is still NULL. :/

Comment: did you add this syntax in ext_typoscript_setup.txt or in setup.txt? those files are different

Answer (score 0):

Okay, problem solved - almost.
I can't get hash values. I don't know why but it is how it is.
I get the values of each column except "identifier_hash", "folder_hash". These attributes are always NULL.

Now I only have to make a new file_reference record in my db when I add a new relation.